# Fstream overwriting in C++ even with ios::app

Tags: c++, file, codeblocks, fstream, overwrite

I have a problem. 
I started a porgram that will save data (Names, surnames, etc...) and saves them to a .txt file. The problem is that it overwrites the data in the file. I have already written ios::app in the fstream file, but doesn't make any difference.
Can you guys help me?

I would give you the code, but it's in Spanish, so I don't think I'll help.

Thanks in advance ;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

const int salario_minimo = 550;

fstream userdata;

int i;

struct FUNCIONARIO{
    char horario;
    char categria;
    int salario_inicial;
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    int id;
    int salario_final;
};

FUNCIONARIO func[18];

int empleados;

int op;

int registrar(){

    userdata.open("FUNCIONARIOS.txt");

    cout << "Escriba el nombre del nuevo funcionario" << endl;
    cin >> func[empleados].nombre;

    cout <<"Escriba el apellido del nuevo funcionario"<<endl;
    cin >> func[empleados].apellido;

    cout<< "Especifique su puesto -Operario(O) o Gerente(G)"<<endl;
    cin >> func[empleados].categria;

    cout << "Especifique su horario -Manana(M), tarde(T) o noche(N)"<<endl;
    cin >> func[empleados].horario;

    i = empleados;
    empleados++;

    for(int o = 0; o < 18; o++){

        int p = o++;
        userdata << i << endl << empleados << endl << func[o].nombre << endl
                 << func[o].apellido << endl << func[o].categria << endl
                 << func[o].horario << endl << func[o].salario_inicial << endl
                 << func[o].salario_final << endl;

        userdata.close();

    }//RESOLVER OVERWRITING URGENTE!!!!!

    cout << "EMPLEADO NUMERO: " << empleados << endl;
    cout << "NOMBRE: " << func[i].nombre << endl;
    cout << "Apellido: " << func[i].apellido << endl;
    cout << "EMPLEO: ";

    switch (func[i].categria){
    case 'G': cout << "GERENTE" << endl; break;
    case 'O': cout << "OPERARIO" << endl; break;
    default: break;
    }

    cout << "HORARIO: ";
    switch(func[i].horario){
    case 'M':
        cout << "MANANA" << endl;
        break;
    case 'T':
        cout << "TARDE" << endl;
        break;
    case 'N':
        cout << "NOCHE" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    cout << "SALARIO INICIAL: " <<func[i].salario_inicial << endl;
    cout << "SALARIO FINAL: " <<func[i].salario_final << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;

}

int main(){

    ifstream comprobador;
    comprobador.open("FUNCIONARIOS.txt");

    if (comprobador.fail()){
        cout << "FILE NOT FOUND" << endl;
        userdata.open("FUNCIONARIOS.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | ios_base::app);
        empleados = 0;
    }else{
        userdata.open("FUNCIONARIOS.txt",fstream::in | fstream::out | ios_base::app);
        userdata >> i >> empleados;
        userdata.close();
    }

    cout << "Numero Actual De Empleados:" << empleados << endl;

    cout << "Bienvenido a BUSINESS MANAGEMENT SOFTWARE 1.0\n Por favor, seleccione una de estas opciones" << endl;

    cout << "1.Registrar Un Nuevo Funcionario\n2.Ver Hojas De Pago\n3.Salir" << endl;

    cin >> op;

    switch (op){
    case (1):
        registrar();
        break;

    /*case 2:
        mostrar();
        break;*/

    default:
        cerr << "Please, Choose A Valid Option" << endl;
        main();
        break;
    }

    userdata.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Well we need to see the code in order to determine what's wrong...

Comment: Spanish is quite popular.

Comment: @pasztorpisti - Particularly in Mexico and Spain

Comment: @EdHeal :-) :-) :-) From wikipedia: "Spanish is the most popular second language learned by native speakers of American English." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language

Comment: @pasztorpisti - Americans struggle with English IMHO. Something happened to the dictionary on the Mayflower

Comment: Nah, it was Noah Webster that decided that English from England was too hard.

Comment: @Aleeo -- It doesn't matter what your native language is.  C++ keywords are the same, regardless of whether you speak Spanish or English.  You don't say `char *p = nuevo char[10];`, do you?

Comment: It doesn't let me upload the code. I format it as code, but it tells me it's not. Can someone post his email and I'll send it.

Comment: Just copy-paste the code into the question, hightlight it and select the `{}` button.

Comment: Done, it is already formatted as code

Comment: Does anyone know what it can be?

Comment: Please sort out the indentation. And why have English in one of the `cerrs` when the rest is in Spanish?

Comment: Sorry, I should have told that I have a very curious way to organize myself :), I sometimes have in Spanish and English to think faster, and then, when everything is solved and complete, translate it to a fix language. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: @Alrro I think I have an idea, but it's hard to grasp what the code is supposed to be doing. Is it ok if I reformat the code? It's barely readable at the moment.

Comment: Sure! Thank you very much for your effort (to everyone!)

Answer (score 0):

There are various possible errors in your code. I will try to highlight the most important ones.

#### Prefer local variables over global ones

There is no need for `i`, `userdata`, `empleados` or `op` to be global. This is C++, not C, scope is very important. There should be no need to call `close` on the `fstream` in this situation.

#### Do not call main recursively

This is not wrong and not exactly dangerous, but it is surely bad practice. The main method is supposed to be called from the runtime and it should be called only once. Also, recursion is not the way to go here, there is no need at all. Just write an infinite loop and use `continue` or `break`/`return` to jump out of it.

Example:

```
while (true) {
    int op = 0;
    cin >> op;

    switch (op) {
    case 1:
        registrar();
        return 0; // Note that break would only break switch, not the while-loop
    default:
        cerr << "Please, Choose A Valid Option" << endl;
        continue;
    }
}
```

#### You call close inside the for-loop

How is this loop supposed to work? It closes `userdata` after the first iteration, then it tries to write into the file 17 more times (which will fail since the file has been closed):

```
for(int o = 0; o < 18; o++){

    int p = o++;
    userdata << /* ... */ endl;

    userdata.close();

}//RESOLVER OVERWRITING URGENTE!!!!!
```

#### Why the file gets overwritten

You open the file on multiple locations, but only on two occasions do you specify `app`. 
Have a look at this part of your code, notice the comments:

```
ifstream comprobador;
comprobador.open("FUNCIONARIOS.txt"); // Open the file for input, no app

if (comprobador.fail()){
    cout << "FILE NOT FOUND" << endl;
    // Ok, file not found, open with append (no need here, it's empty anyway!)
    userdata.open("FUNCIONARIOS.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | ios_base::app);
    empleados = 0;
}else{
    // File already found and still open for input, reopen with new fstream
    // and specify append
    userdata.open("FUNCIONARIOS.txt",fstream::in | fstream::out | ios_base::app);
    // app places the filecursor at the end, the next statement will not work!
    userdata >> i >> empleados;
    // Now you close the file again!
    userdata.close();
}
```

So basically in the first case the file is empty and open, in the second case the file has been opened shortly but closed right afterwards. This is not good, the `if` should leave `userdata` in a consistent state. Now imagine the file is closed (`else`-statement) and you call `registrar`. On the first line of `registrar` is this statement:

```
userdata.open("FUNCIONARIOS.txt");
```

You open the file again, this time without specifying `app`.

I would suggest to open the file *once* in your program using `ifstream` for input, reading all entries (if any) into the memory, add new entries and then writing the file *once* using `ofstream` with `ios::trunc` specified, to rewrite all entries to the file, or instead open the file using `ofstream` with `ios::app` specified and only add one entry. You have to parse through the file first since you need the number for `empleados` from the last line. If you open the file inside a scope `{ ... }`, it will close itself at the end, no need to call close. You also do not need to call `open` if you construct the fstream directly with the filename and flags specified. An example:

```
void registrar() {

    // ...

    ofstream file("FUNCIONARIOS.txt", ios::app);

    if (file) {
        file << /* ... */ endl;
    }

} // file will be closed here because ofstreams destructor is called
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! WORKED PERFECTLY! Now do you know how to get a undefined number of data in the files? I mean, I saw I cant do like `int l = 0; int k = empleados - 1; do{
        datain >>func[l].nombre>>func[l].apellido
        >>func[l].categria>>func[l].horario>>func[l].salario_inicial
        >>func[l].salario_final;
        l++;

     }while(l != k);` How can I do it then?

Comment: In order to assing the value to the variables with the data shown, one variable = one line.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could use something like this:
`while (datain && k < empleados) { datain >> func[l].nombre >> func[l].appelido /*...*/; ++l }
This will read data into the `func[l]` until the filestream reaches eof or the count of `empleados` has been reached. It will also stop the loop if an error occured while reading from the stream.

Comment: If the number is really not known at all you should not use a static array. Instead use `std::vector` to store the items.

Comment: But how can I assing the value of  the  variables according to the number of lines written? Don´t know if you understand.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. You might want to ask a new question. If you mean that you don't know `empleados` upfront you can simply stream until you reach `eof()` (end of file) and count up `empleados` and `l` as you read each element.

Comment: I mean, I want to know how many lines the ofstream file has and then use `datain >> func[l].whatever` until the last line of datain autmatically. Thank you anyways

Comment: You don't need to know how many lines there are upfront. Just read: `while (datain) { datain >> func[l].whatever; ++l; }`. `l` will contain the number of lines - 1 afterwards if every read was one line.

Comment: It doesn´t assing the values, the assing them all for the same line

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I don't understand your problem. Please post a new question with the code that is troubling you and try to describe the issue using that code.